# Restrict FTP user to a directory

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, users, ftp, sftp

On a Ubuntu 11.04 server, I want to restrict a user to a specific directory (so he can't access the parents' directory) for FTP/ssh.
I created the user with `adduser username` and changed the target directory with `usermod -d /home/path/to/directory username`. This worked perfectly.

From what I found I have to modify a `/etc/ftp/ftpaccess` file but the file (and the ftp) directory does not exist. I tried creating it but it didn't change anything. Also I only want to restrict *this* user and not the others.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey one query, if the session is an anonymous one. How can I limit it to a specific directory.?

Answer (score 9):

The best way, is to use SFTP from SSH and jail the user.

in file: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

make sure this line is uncomented:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Then configure the rule to match a group:

```
Match group sftponly
         ChrootDirectory /home/%u
         X11Forwarding no
         AllowTcpForwarding no
         ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

and lastly manage the users:

```
# chown root.root /home/user
# usermod -d / user
# adduser user sftponly
```

Source: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590

Comment: For not affecting the usage of sftp for users that belong to a group other than "sftponly" (i.e. keeping), could I specify the Subsystem command inside the match, leaving the previous configuration unchanged?

Comment: Hey one query, if the session is an anonymous one. How can I limit it to a specific directory.?

Answer (score 3):

A bit late in the day but it may help others in the future. I installed VSFTPD and edited the configuration file vsftpd.conf so it includes:-

```
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

You need to restart the service after editings:-

```
service vsftpd restart
```

The FTP Users  are restricted to Home Directory specified when adding them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a FTP Server first!
Read the documentation:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FtpServer

You need to chose one of the FTP Servers in the comment **↓**.. Or if you have already installed SSH you can use SFTP.. To do this, just on your FTP client type:

- Host: sftp://ssh_server_hostname_or_ip
- login:your_ssh_server_user_name
- pass: your_ssh_server_user_password

You'll be able to r/w on all the directories that belong to your ssh user

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd
*****
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PureFTP
*****
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ProFTPD

Comment: The ssh / sftp login works, I just want to restrict the user to a directory

Answer (score 0):

add a guestuser option to the ftpaccess file in the /etc directory

Comment: Are you saying that `/etc/ftpaccess` is the correct path to the configuration file? What should this `guestuser` option look like?

Comment: OP cannot find the `ftpaccess` file, and that is quite likely since there are several `ftp` implementations out there.  You should outline at least on implementation (preferably several) and tell how to make a distinction between them.